# Is the built-in Windows Server 2012 DNS Server adequate for performance?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012, google-dns

I'm hosting several host header website in IIS on a 2012 R2 box that need to be accessible both inside and outside the network (WAN) via subdomain names.  For WAN access, foo.example.com resolves to my WANIP adresss.  From the LAN side I need to setup a DNS server and will manually add foo.example.com, bar.example.com etc.

My LAN clients, which will be using DHCP will first point to my LAN DNS server to handle all example.com subdomains and then Google's 8.8.4.4 for all other DNS resolution.

Is Windows built-in DNS server a good choice in terms of performance, or should I use another implementation?  Could I also have my internal DNS use my custom entires first then use 8.8.8.8 for everything else?  Would that basically equate to using google DNS for everything but my entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't know about performance of windows DNS server vs any other.
What i do know is that in the windows DNS Server u can easially make a DNS record for an external dns name. the record you made will always be used and the DNS server will only look at its forwarders(google dns for example) when it doesnt know the record itself.

To make a new zone (external DNS Record) right click **Forward Lookup Zones**

Choose **New Zone**

Select **Primary Zone**

Select **To all DNS Servers running on domain controllers in this domain**

**Zone Name** fill in the URL Example: google.com   or drive.google.com  ps. If you do for example google.com all dns queries including the ones for its subdomains will be dealt with by your DNS server, it wont look it up externaly, so best to make the zone for the subdomain where possible.

Select **Allow only secure dynamic updates**

Click **finish**

Now you have made the zone, only there are no Records in it, so all queries will fail.
Create a ARecord without a host name and it will be the default ip for the domain

Comment: How would add the record for the external DNS?

Comment: updated my answer